# Wix *.msi installer Icon and logos

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6, wix3.7

According to this
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry

I have created the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="0.0.1.4" Manufacturer="my" UpgradeCode="*">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <!--icon for Add/Remove Programs-->
    <Icon Id="WINDOWS.ico" SourceFile="..\WINDOWS.ico" />
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="WINDOWS.ico" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1" Description="The complete installation" Display="expand" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="ProgramMenuDir" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExportReleaseComponentGroup" />          
    </Feature>
    <!--Internal tools-->
    <Feature Id="Internal_Calibration_tools" Title="Internal Calibration tools" Level="1000" Description="Internal tools">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="group_Internal_Calibration_tools" />
    </Feature>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo"></UIRef>
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIExclamationIco" Value="..\Import\WINDOWS_32px.ico" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIInfoIco" Value="..\Import\WINDOWS_32px.ico" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUINewIco" Value="..\Import\WINDOWS_16px.ico" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIUpIco" Value="..\Import\WINDOWS_16px.ico" />
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
```

However I still can't see the icons changing.
[image]

[image]

in bootstrap everything works fine and all of the icons were changed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should add this. The whole top banner image should be added.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="..\images\banner.bmp" />
```

Make sure its in the correct size and it must be a bitmap image.

Reference : http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html

Answer (score 6):

You are showing an image of the Top Banner if you want to change that, you need to create a 493 × 58 bitmap, that will serve as the background layer for the dialogues titles and texts.

So add this line in the Product element:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ImagesDir)\[YOUR BITMAP HERE].bmp" />
```

You'll find the other WixVariables you need to change the default WIX UI [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html)